# Intellij DB Console file cache?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea2017

Long story short, I wrote this really nice SQL query a few days ago.
Then I closed the DB console tab with that query on it and cannot locate it anywhere.

Has the file been lost, or is it some IntelliJ cached / system folder?

The reason I ask, is because when you open a new DB console, the tab has a different indice on it, which leads me to believe that, there is some persistence of those files somewhere?

[image]

Any other way I can recover this query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your old consoles will live underneath the Scratches subdirectory.  In your project view, click the button that says "Project".

[image]

From that drop-down menu, select "Scratches".  You'll see the "Database Consoles" folder there, and that should contain any SQL queries that you haven't actively removed from your DB console.